# React native: which navigator is more flexible?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm considering a navigator for a new react-native project

I think the best 2 options are [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/) and [react native navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/)

Which one is more flexible in terms of defining custom navbars (for example a  toggle searchbar) and overriding the default back button handler (for example: to prompt a 'save changes?' warning)?

Answer (score 1):

I would say `react-navigation` is a better choice, in terms of its flexible api.

Also check out this post from Eric Vicenti, if you are trying to choose the way to go in terms of navigation and navigation animations;

> https://medium.com/@ericvicenti/playing-with-react-navigation-and-airbnbs-native-navigation-4e49fc765489